# Can't update conda packages due to "RemoveError"

Tags: anaconda, conda

I run the command `conda update --all` and encountered the error as shown in the snapshot below.

[image]
[image]

It seems the `packaging` python python is preventing an update. How can this error be fixed?

I am running Anaconda v2023 on Windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot replicate this error.  You can try to update conda first to see if a newer version of conda clears this up.

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still get the same error. I guess I may have no choice but to upgrade to the latest Anaconda v2024 version. I'm using v2023